# WCF Broadcast message to all clients

Tags: c#, wcf, message, broadcast

I have a WCF service and client application - I'm using named pipes in this case. Service and client are able to communicate each other. All I want to do is to use callback method to broadcast message to all clients.

In service I have two methods used by clients to register themselves in service:

Dictionary to store information about the particular client:

```
private static Dictionary<Guid, ICallbacks> clients = new Dictionary<Guid, ICallbacks>();
```

Method to register client in service:

```
public void RegisterInService(Guid clientID)
{
            ICallbacks callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallbacks>();

            lock (clients)
            {
                if (!clients.ContainsKey(clientID))
                {
                    clients.Add(clientID, callback);
                }
            }
}
```

Method to un-register client:

```
public void UnregisterFromService(Guid clientID)
{
            lock(clients)
            {
                if (clients.ContainsKey(clientID))
                    clients.Remove(clientID);
            }
}
```

The WCF service behavior has been configured in following way:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

Now, in service I have another method, let's say for more "advanced" operations. In this method I would like to execute another method to broadcast message to all registered clients.

Here is the code:

```
public void MainProcessActions()
{

            SendMessageToAllClients("Send to all clients ...");
}

private void SendMessageToAllClients(string data)
{
            StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"E:\Temp\ClientsInvokingEvidence.txt", true);

            lock (clients)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, ICallbacks> client in clients)
                {

                    client.Value.UpdateClientData(data);

                    file.WriteLine("Invoking method for client ID : {0}", client.Key);

                }
            }

            file.Close();

}
```

Here is the callback method declaration in interface:

```
public interface ICallbacks
{
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void UpdateClientData(string data);
}
```

Now, let's say I have three instances of the client in memory (one application executed three times). Once I call method `MainProcessActions()` from one of the clients the callback method is executed only for this particular client. It seems that callback method `UpdateClientData(string data)` is ignored by other clients.

Can you guys give me some tips how can I solve this problem?

In nutshell I would like to send data from service to all registered clients.

**#edit**

I have some updates. The `UpdateClientData(string data)` method is actually executed by all clients... The problem is with using data received from the service to set the TextBox control in Windows Form.

Here is the body of this method:

```
public void UpdateClientData(string data)
{
     this.DataFromService = data;
}
```

Later in code I'm using property `DataFromService` to set text in TextBox control in MainForm class.

It looks like the text of the TextBox control can be set by only one instance of client...

The interesting thing is that when I pass reference to the TextBox control to class that implements the `UpdateClientData` method then I'm able to set text in TextBox control in all clients at once.

Any advice?

**#edit**

Here is the part of the code where I'm using DataFromService property.

This property is a member of following class:

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
class WCFServiceCommunication : ICallbacks
{
    public string DataFromService;

    ...

    public WCFServiceCommunication()
    {
        binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();

        pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IGeneralContract>(this, binding, new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/SomeName"));

        pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

        ClientID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public void ExecuteOnServiceSide()
    {
        pipeProxy.MainProcessActions();
    }

    public void RegisterClient()
    {
        pipeProxy.RegisterInService(ClientID);
    }

    public void UnregisterClient()
    {
        pipeProxy.UnregisterFromService(ClientID);
    }

    public void UpdateClientData(string data)
    {
        // here I'm able to verify that this method actually has been invoked by service for each instance of the client

        DataFromService = data;
    }

}
```

In UI code (Windows Form):

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    private WCFServiceCommunication wcfCommunication;
    ....

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitalizeComponent();

        wcfCommunication = new WCFServiceCommunication();

        wcfCommunication.RegisterClient();

    }

    ...

    private void btnCheckForUpdates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here, on service side method MainProcessActions() is called
        // in this method I'm calling broadcast method
        wcfCommunication.ExecuteOnServiceSide();

        textBox1.Text = wcfCommunication.DataFromService;
    }
}
```

Another interesting thing. When I move whole service communication configuration (creating channels, implementation of the callback method) into the MainForm class, then everything works fine - I'm able to set TextBox for all instances of the client.

Regards!

Comment: You say "Later in code I'm using property DataFromService to set text in TextBox control in MainForm class.". Could you show this code?

Comment: Hello Igor. Take a look on the post - it has been updated and now contains code mentioned by you.

Comment: Sorry for being away - it was vacation time. If the question is still relevant, I would suggest to modify `CallbackBehavior` attribute and add `ConcurencyMode=Multiple` (or at least `Reentrant`) there. By default it is single, which means that while one thread (UI one) is executing `ExecuteOnServiceSide` method the callback will not start.